# Question regarding triangle inequality in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

This is probably a trivial question. It is regarding some notes I took from class in real analysis. First of all, I know that in a metric space with metric d and underlying set $S$, if we let $x,y,z \in S$, then $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. Doing some algebra, we get $d(y,z) \geq d(x,z) - d(x,y)$. But is it also true that $d(y,z) \geq |d(x,z) - d(x,y)|$ ?? This is what he wrote and I don't see how to get there. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have already shown $d(y,z) > d(x,z) - d(x,y)$, you need to show $d(y,z) > d(x,y) - d(x,z)$ to be done. This is easy since by the triangle inequality $d(x,y) < d(x,z) + d(y,z)$
from which the inequality comes immediately.